# Adding users from a text file into active directoy

Tags: ruby, active-directory

I've been working on this code for ages and I can't get it working. It takes user information form a text file, creates user groups and puts the users in the groups. It makes the security group just fine, but it does not put the users in the groups. There is no error message but after going through the error checking is goes through the code that should add the user and puts the error at the bottom. Can anyone help please?

The usernames in the text file are setup like so:

```
fred,bush,1990-20-3,123456781,2008-20-3,D5,

xin,zhao,1990-20-2,123456782,2008-20-3,D5,

bobby,bob,1990-20-1,123456783,2008-20-3,D5,

john,lose,1990-20-4,123456784,2008-20-3,D5,

elly,moose,1990-20-5,123456785,2008-20-3,D5,

jackie,chan,1990-20-6,123456786,2008-20-3,D5,

katarina,lotus,1990-20-7,123456787,2008-20-3,D5,

kelly,nunu,1990-20-8,123456788,2008-20-3,D5,

lois,harris,1990-20-9,123456789,2008-20-3,D5,

gutwold,manly,1990-20-10,123456780,2008-20-3,D5,

griswold,womenly,1990-20-11,123456710,2008-20-3,D5,

bessy,horse,1990-20-12,123456711,2008-20-3,D5,
```

And the code is:

```
require 'date'
domain = "dc=TROPTRAIN,dc=net,dc=au"
ou = "ou=studentsOU"
filepath = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Luke Abbey Ruby Final\userfile\error_log.txt'
users = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Luke Abbey Ruby Final\userfile\newusers.txt'

#intro function for the program
def intro
    system "cls"
    puts ""
    puts "  Tropical Train - Adding users"
    puts "====================================================================="
    puts ""
end

#get user file
check = 0
while check == 0
    intro
    puts "Please enter the path to the user file,"
    puts "or enter the the letter 's' to use the stored file location:"
    puts ""
    puts "#{users}"
    userfile = gets.chomp.to_s
    if ((userfile == 's') || (userfile == 'S'))
        check = 1
        userfile = users

        #puts userfile
        #system "pause"
    elsif(test(?e,userfile))
        check = 1
    elsif userfile =~ (/[\x00\/\\:\*\?\"<>\|]/)
        puts "The userfile contains invalid characters. Try again."
        system "pause"
        check = 0
    elsif userfile == ""
        puts "You entered nothing. Try again."
        system "pause"
        check = 0
    elsif(!test(?e,userfile))
        check = 0
        puts "The file #{userfile} does not exist. Try again."
        system "pause"
    else 
        puts "Your entry is invalid. Try again."
        system "pause"
        check = 0
    end
end

#create the security groups via DOS and check wheteher they already exist
grpC2 = 0
grpC3 = 0
grpC4 = 0
grpD5 = 0
expired = 0
students = 0
%x[dsquery group "dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"].each do |line|
    data = line
    if line.include?("grpC2")
        grpC2 = 1
    end
    if line.include?("grpC3")
        grpC3 = 1
    end
    if line.include?("grpC4")
        grpC4 = 1
    end
    if line.include?("grpD5")
        grpD5 = 1
    end
    if line.include?("Expired")
        expired = 1
    end
    if line.include?("Students")
        students = 1
    end
end
if grpC2 != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=grpC2,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end
if grpC3 != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=grpC3,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end
if grpC4 != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=grpC4,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end
if grpD5 != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=grpD5,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end
if expired != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=Expired,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end
if students != 1
    %x[dsadd group "cn=Students,ou=studentsOU,dc=troptrain,dc=net,dc=au"]
end

#open the file
f1 = File.open(userfile,"r")

#read the file line by line
count = 0
f1.each do |line|
    data = line.split(',')
    firstname = data[0].capitalize
    surname = data[1].capitalize
    dob = data[2].to_s
    snumber = data[3].to_s
    enddate1 = data [4].gsub!("-","/")
    enddate = enddate1
    area = data[5]
    fullname = (firstname + (" ") + surname)
    group = "cn=#{'grp'+data[5]}"
    password1 = data[2].gsub("-", "")
    password = password1
    count = count + 1
    #display values for establishing error checks
    #puts ""
    #puts "fullname:   #{fullname}"
    #puts "dob:        #{dob}"
    #puts "snumber:    #{snumber}"
    #puts "enddate:    #{enddate}"
    #puts "area:       #{area}"
    #puts "password:   #{password}"
    #puts "group:      #{group}"
    #puts "count:      #{count}"
    #puts ""
    if ((data[2] =~ /[^0-9-]/) || (data[3] =~ /[^0-9-]/) || (data[4] =~ /[^0-9\/]/) ||    (data[5] =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/) || (data[0] =~ /[^A-Za-z ]/) || (data[1] =~ /[^A-Za-z ]/) || (data[0] == "") || (data[1] == "") || (data[2] == "") || (data[3] == "") || (data[4] == "") || (data[5] == "") || (data[6] == ""))
        puts ""    
        puts "====================================================================="
        puts "User account No #{count}: #{fullname} was not created."
        puts ""
        if (File.exist?(filepath))
            file = File.open((filepath), "a+")
            t = Time.now    
            file.puts "====================================================================="
            file.puts "User account No #{count}: #{fullname} was not created."
            file.puts t
            file.puts ""
        else
            puts "Error log cannot be found!"
            puts "Searched directory: #{filepath}"
        end

        #checking database entries for errors
        if ((data[0] == "") || (data[0] =~ /[^A-Za-z ]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect firstname on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect firstname on file."
        end     
        if ((data[1] == "") || (data[1] =~ /[^A-Za-z ]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect surname on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect surname on file."
        end
        if ((data[2] == "") || (data[2] =~ /[^0-9-]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect birthdate on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect birthdate on file."
        end
        if ((data[3] == "") || (data[3] =~ /[^0-9-]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect student number on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect student number on file."
        end
        if ((data[4] == "") || (data[4] =~ /[^0-9\/]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect study end date on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect study end date on file."
        end
        if ((data[5] == "") || (data[5] =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/))
            puts "No/Incorrect study area on file."
            file.puts "No/Incorrect study area on file."
        end
        file.close
    else
        begin
            puts "working"
            system 'pause'
            ad = WIN32OLE.connect("LDAP://#{ou},#{domain}")
            user = ad.create("user","cn=#{fullname}")
            user.givenName = firstname
            user.Sn = surname
            user.SAMAccountname = "#{snumber}"
            user.userPrincipalName = "#{snumber}@Troptrain.net.au"
            user.displayName = fullname
            user.profilePath = "c:\\profiles\\students\\logon"
            user.setInfo

            user_fqdn = "cn=#{fullname},#{ou},#{domain}"
            user = WIN32OLE.connect("LDAP://#{user_fqdn}")
            user.userPassword = Password01
            user.accountDisabled = 0
            user.accountExpirationDate = enddate

            user.setInfo

            studentgroup_fqdn = "#{group},#{ou},#{domain}"
            grp = WIN32OLE.connect("LDAP://#{studentgroup_fqdn}")
            grp.add("LDAP://#{user_fqdn}")

            allgroup_fqdn = "cn=students,#{ou},#{domain}"
            allgrp = WIN32OLE.connect("LDAP://#{allgroup_fqdn}")
            allgrp.add("LDAP://#{user_fqdn}")

            puts ""
            puts "====================================================================="
            puts "User account No #{count}: #{fullname} was created."
            sleep 0.5

        rescue

        end
    end
end
puts "====================================================================="
puts ""
puts "See Error log for details."
puts ""
puts "The program has finished creating users."
f1.close
```

Comment: The indentation is all over the place with this file; can you [edit] the post with a version with consistent indentation?

Comment: i re-indented it to make it a bit easier.

Comment: It's definitely improved, but I still see e.g. two consecutive `end` lines in the first column. The interpreter just uses the nesting to know what's going on, but it's immensely hard for humans to read incorrectly indented code. I wonder if there's a mechanical way to force a re-indent of an entire program in the Ruby language? (My usual tool, `indent(1)`, is for C and similar languages. Ruby is a definite non-starter.)

Comment: It turns out that `vim` can do a _great_ job re-indenting code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194185/where-can-i-find-a-decent-ruby-source-beautifier

Comment: ty for the indenting help, but is anyone able to see why the program is not working?

Comment: if no one knows how to fix the current code, could some show me the code for adding users into active directory?

Answer (score 2):

Separate your concerns.

1. You need to parse a text file and retrieve users and groups from it in a structured way.
2. You need to import your groups and then import your users.
3. You then assign the users to the groups you created.
4. Each User and Group must be located in their own OUs to identify them.
5. Those OUs must be known.

Now work backward and factor out everything you need to continue with.

1. Find your host name, port and the credentials to bind to the LDAP server.
2. Find your Base DN. (`DC=troptrain, DC=net, DC=au`)
3. Find your User and Group prefixes. (the OU segments after the Base DN).
4. Import your data.
5. Verify. (This is also important!)

As LDAP can appear to be somewhat backward from the typical relational database, I recommend using the ActiveLDAP ruby gem with `gem install active_ldap`. It makes working with LDAP far easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'active_ldap'

class User < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'CN', :prefix => '<user-ou-prefix>',
  has_many :groups, :class => 'Group', :wrap => 'memberOf', :primary_key => 'DN'
end

class Group < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'CN', :prefix => '<group-ou-prefix>',
  has_many :members, :class => 'User', :wrap => 'member', :primary_key => 'DN' 
end

ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection(
  :host => '<hostname>',
  :base => '<base-dn>',
  :bind_dn  => '<bind-dn>',
  :password => '<bind-password>',
  :allow_anonymous => false,
  :try_sasl => false,
  :port => 389
)
```

From there, you should have the ability to create, read, update, and delete users using an ActiveRecord-like interface. the call to `#setup_connection` establishes what options are used to connect, and the `has_many` calls establish foreign-key-like relations between your classes.

```
# Find and display all users:
User.find(:all, '*') do |user|
  puts user.cn
end

# Create a group with a CN of 'Anonymous'
group = Group.new('Anonymous')
group.description = "An anonymous group."
group.save

# Change the user with the CN 'Nobody' and change their displayName attribute.
user = User.find('Nobody')
user.displayName = "Nobody's Name"
user.save

# Delete a group with a CN of 'Foobar'.
group = Group.find('Foobar')
group.delete
```

ActiveLdap makes it *extremely* easy to manipulate LDAP from Ruby, I highly recommend it.

Comment: Excellent answer providing both advice on high-level structuring _and_ the details necessary to drive LDAP in an _elegant_ fashion. Providing both `Group` and `User` classes like this is taking Ruby beyond a scripting tool into the realm of simple, expressive, power.